# MVP - How to expose specific properties of my Model

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I am using the MVP pattern in a C# winforms application and came across the following design issue. I have a `User` class in my domain and a `UserCollectionDAO` class that essentially loads all users with some other bits of information from a database. When I am presenting a collection of users to my view via the presenter I do not want to show all their properties. For example my User has the following properties:

```
class User
{
   public User(int id)
   {
      Id = id;
   } 

   public int Id { get; private set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public LocationId { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to show in my `Listview` of users is the Name and the name of the Location which I can get from another data structure in my system. At the same time I want to use the LocationId and the Id in other areas of my application. I have read about another layer that one might need to use, that of DTO objects. What is your opinion on that and can you see another way of achieving what I want? How can I pass information from the View to the DTO User instance to the domain User instance?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would have your domain class/model get converted to a ViewModel (a model specific to a particular view, hiding particular properties of your model).

At the [domain services layer](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) create a method that converts your model to a view model or use a library like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) to autoconvert it to you. Some of the properties on your domain user class *might* need to be public (why aren't they?) to be copied over automatically by AutoMapper.

Further reading: [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

Comment: Thanks that sounds logical. I edited the private properties, it was a simple typing mistake.